# Two sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Tags: large-data, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have multiple sets of large (n,m>1500) experimental data and I am comparing 2 of the datasets at a time. I thought the two sample Kolomogrov-Smirnov test would be a good way to see if my datasets are similar. However, due to the sample sizes being so large, the C($\alpha$) and $p$-values are quite small, therefore, in all cases the null hypothesis is rejected and the datasets all are considered different.

Is there a better test to use to compare large experimental datasets. Or is there a way that I can characterize these results by just using the $D_{m}$ values and just ranking them in order of smallest to largest to see where my data has the least difference, and thus, more experimentally reproducible compared to the others?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. $\alpha$ is something you choose before you see any data. Do you instead mean that the $p$-values are "quite small"? 2. If you're trying to use a weaker test because your test is consistent (i.e. actually has power approaching 1 at large sample sizes),  rather than indicating fyou look for a worse test, it suggests that you don't have a hypothesis testing problem *at all* -- if large samples cause you to balk at rejecting, your real question is something not answered by a NHST -- even if you'd had small $n$. This is discussed in numerous answers on site (but usually about other tests).

Comment: 3. If you're doing many two-sample tests, note the multiple testing problem. (There are some k-sample tests that might be considered, unless your interest is really on each pairwise test,)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, sorry I mean the C($\alpha$) and $p$ value, because even if I choose a very low significance level ($\alpha$ = 0.0001) the datasets are still not similar.

Comment: A bit of background... I want to compare just two datasets at a time because I ran an experiment  twice ( so I have 2 replicas). However, because it is experimental data, I think there is more room for error. But through a test I want to see some similarities in the datasets to prove that, yes indeed, they are the same experiments. Or at least, which of the datasets are more similar.

Comment: You have pairs of samples and you're just comparing within each pair?

Comment: Are you trying to pick the pair which are closest?

Comment: Yes, as well as other pairs of samples that I would like to compare because one of the variables was changed

Comment: Yes, I am trying to figure out which ones are closest. and wondering if by just comparing the $D_{m}$ values this would be valid?